# Add shadow borders to custom drawn window

Tags: python, winapi, user-interface, tkinter, wxwidgets

I'm designing a custom drawn window with Tkinter (or any other, like wxWidgets)

```
import Tkinter as tk
app=tk.Tk()
app.overrideredirect(True)
app.geometry("500x500+100+100")
app.mainloop()
```

I would like to have shadow borders outside of the window like this (fade to black / gradient) :

**How to add such shadow borders?**

[image]

Comment: That is the window manager's job, not your application's. It therefore depends on the window manager you're using.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : I want to have a **custom drawn window** (I don't want classical Windows window look). The only solution solution I have found for this is to use `app.overrideredirect(True)` in Python. Do you know an another way to do it ? If so I'm interested.
Second thing : once you use `app.overrideredirect(True)`, there is no more shadow borders. Do you know a solution in order to restore those shadows ?

Comment: By using `overrideredirect(True)`, you're basically telling the window manager to ignore your window. Problem is, any decoration you implement will be clipped to the window's area, it cannot "spill" outside. So, I'm afraid you cannot implement shadow borders that way.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : Ok. So is there a way to redecorate the title bar and the borders like in the screenshot in my question, without using `overrideredirect(True)` ? I'm okay to use `win32` things instead of using premade `tkinter` functions. (I don't want to have such borders/title bar : http://files.techtalkz.com/Windows-7-Guides/build-7000/windows-7-automatic-updates/1.jpg.... I do *know* it is better for many reasons to keep the OS native UI, but I really want custom design).

Comment: There are ways on Windows (look up "custom non-client area"), but it depends on the window manager on *NIX systems. I never encountered a WM that let you customize decorations on a per-window basis, but I don't know them all. In any case, you will have to write non-portable code.

Comment: My app wil be portable : `if` Windows `then` (custom drawn window with specific code), `elif` Mac or *NIX `then` (keep native OS window)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thanks to your keywords `custom non-client area`, I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#hittest which could be very useful. Do you think using such techniques (what is described in this link) is possible in Python, how ?